# insert multiple tables and populate GUI table

Tags: jdbc

I am developing a GUI which contains a table with 8 columns, (A,B,C,D,E,F,G)

In the database I have two tables. Table1 contains (A,B,C,D,E+) and Table2 contains (E,F,G). Here E+ is FK to Table1.

Now I want to insert using a prepared statement and then popluate GUI table. I am writing the insert query as follows. The E+ FK in Table1 is to popluate values of Table2.

```
insert into table1 (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) values (?,?,?,?,(select t2.E from t2 where t2.E=2)

ps.setString(1,a)
ps.setString(2,b)
ps.setString(3,b)
...
```

By using above query I am not able to insert into DB as well as GUI table. Please let me know the correct query.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite confusing:

> I am developing a GUI which contains a table with 8 columns, (A,B,C,D,E,F,G)

That makes 7 columns, not 8.

> In the database I have two tables. Table1 contains (A,B,C,D,E+) and Table2 contains (E,F,G). Here E+ is FK to Table1.

Why would Table1 contain a foreign key to itself?

> insert into table1 (a,b,c,d,e,f,g)

How can you imagine this would work, since table 1 doesn't have any column named e, f, and g?

---

First of all, separate the database stuff from the GUI stuff into distinct classes. The two aspects should not be mixed together.

Then learn about SQL. If you want to insert into 2 tables, you need 2 insert statements: one which inserts into table1, and another one that inserts into table2. If the FK is in table2, then the first insert must be the insert in table1, since the FK in table2 must reference a row that exists in table1.

Comment: Thanks. I am fine with inserting 2 insert statement. But how to display those values in GUI... which has 8 coulmns (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H)

Comment: And also i guess i should use 2 prepared statements

Comment: Use a query that selects all the columns at once (assuming you have a one-to-one association between table1 and table2): `select t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t1.d, t1.e, t2.f, t2.g from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.e = t2.e where ... `

Comment: To say thanks, here, you upvote an answer you found useful. And if the answer was the best answer you got and answered your question, you mark it as accepted. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work